# Fatal error: Call to a member function load() - Kohana PHP

Tags: php, kohana

I just set up a Repo for a kohana project on my laptop.

I modified the DB credentials file. However I am getting this issue (same issue that i was getting before)

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/gosnipe/site/system/classes/kohana/core.php on line 649
```

so the repo works. It works on another guys laptop, however I can't figure out why it's not working for me.

Comment: Maybe your framework isn't installed correctly - missing files, corrupt download ?

Comment: It should be installed correctly, since installation means a bunch of files in the right folder in this case? @André

Comment: What version of Kohana are you using? Could you add the code it is breaking at (core.php line 649)

Comment: this is the line. Idk about the version, I think the newest and this code was working on friends computer. @DanielThompson       $config[$group] = Kohana::$config->load($group);

Comment: @bezzoon please add the `$config[$group] = Kohana::$config->load($group);` code to your question together with the name of the file that it is being called from. The Kohana version can be found in this file `classes/Kohana/Core.php` - look for the value of const VERSION and add it to your question as well.

Comment: @bezzoon Did you finally find out the cause? Now I'm having the same error. Line: `$config = Kohana::$config->load('my_config');`

Answer (score 3):

I've found the (very strange) problem. The **application/cache** directory does not exists, BUT there was not error about this missing directory. When I created cache directory (**application/cache**) and changed permission for it problem solved.